# Sumario para PDF com Dompdf/dompdf

Tags: php, composer, dompdf

Estou utilizando o DOMPDF para montar meus relatórios, porem não consigo relacionar no sumario os índices de respectivos tópicos.

```
 session_start();
    
    require  __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";
    use Dompdf\Dompdf; 
    use Dompdf\Options;
    $options = new Options();
    $options->setIsPhpEnabled(true);
    $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
    
    $sumario = '';
    foreach($_SESSION['sumario'] as $index=>$titulo){
        $sumario .=   "<div>";                
            $sumario .="<span>{$index}. {$titulo}</span>";
            $sumario .="<p>x</p>"; // Aqui mora o problema, não consigo relacionar este valor!          
        $sumario .="</div>";
    }
    ob_start();
        $documento =  $_SESSION['documento'];
        require __DIR__."/pdf.php";
    $pdf = ob_get_clean();
    
   
    //echo $pdf; die;
    
    $dompdf->loadHtml($pdf);

    $dompdf->setPaper("A4");
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("file.pdf",["Attachment" => false]);
```

Fiz de uma maneira bem simples, o $_SESSION['documento']  é basicamente um arquivo html, onde os 'h1' são os topicos, 'h2' subtopicos e 'p' são os textos comuns.

O $_SESSION['sumario'] foi uma coisa que fiz no desespero, tentando fazer o sumario. Ele está da seguinte forma :

```
$_SESSION['sumario'] = array(
       [1] => 'Titulo 01',
       [2] => 'Titulo 02',
       [3] => 'Titulo 03
);
```

Ambas as sessões infetadas em "pdf.php";

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se entendi bem mas você precisa fazer um link no sumário que leve a página em questão, correto? Se sim, você precisa ancorar seus links.

```
<!-- Links do sumário deverão ser dessa forma -->
<a href="#pagina1"> Ir para página 1 </a>

<!-- coloque uma âncora em cada página, o número ou título da página, por exemplo  -->
<a name="pagina1"> 1 </a>
```

Caso não funcione você pode tentar substituir o `<a name>` por algum elemento com o mesmo ID

`<span id="pagina1"></span>`

Comment: Seu exemplo vai me servir, porém não é isso que estou precisando. Acho que fui um pouco confuso na pergunta, então dei uma editada para tentar ser mais preciso.  O que eu preciso é numero o sumario com as paginas de cada topico.

Comment: Ainda não consegui entender. O que seria o "X" no `<p>x</p>`?

Comment: Serio aonde eu colocaria o a pagina do tópico. Por exemplo  se o Titulo 01, estivesse na pagina 02,  ficaria <span>1. Titulo 01</span><p>02</p>";